# Filtering and sorting by a specified child in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, subquery

I am building a game app using Firebase and Swift, and store my data like this.

```
players: {
   "category": {
       "playerId": {
         name: "Joe", 
         score: 3
       }
   }
}
```

There are two queries I need to make based on the score:

- Get the top 5 players from a single category.
- Get the overall top 100 players of the game.

I have no problem getting the data for the first query, using

```
 ref.child("players").child(category).queryOrdered(byChild: "score").queryLimited(toLast:5)
```

But I am having trouble figuring out the second query. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this, because it seems like a valid question. I counter-upvoted.

Comment: Is it acceptable to you that you change the structure of your database?I think if you change the structure it would be easy

Comment: Yes, the structure can be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll either need to add an additional data structure to allow the second query (which is quite common in NoSQL databases) or change your current structure to allow both queries.

The latter could be accomplished by turning the data into a single flat list, with some additional synthetic properties. E.g.

```
players: {
   "playerId": {
     category: "category1"
     name: "Joe", 
     score: 3,
     category_score: "category1_3"
   }
}
```

With the new additional properties `category` and `category_score`, you can get the top scorers for a category with:

```
ref.child("players")
   .queryOrdered(byChild: "category_score")
   .queryStarting(atValue:"category1_")
   .queryEnding(atValue("category1_~")
   .queryLimited(toLast:5)
```

And the top 100 scores overall with:

```
ref.child("players")
   .queryOrdered(byChild: "score")
   .queryLimited(toLast:100)
```

For more on this, see my answer here: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase.